# How to pass down ng* attributes in a custom directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've created a custom "bs-input" directive that wraps an input field into a bootstrap template. It works allright if I fill in all the attributes (type, max-length, required, pattern, etc). However,

```
<bs-input ng-model="something">
```

does not work. The field is considered invalid, because of maxlength validation and ng-pattern validation (e.g. no regexp). How can I pass undefined variables to the input tag, or conditionally exclude them if they do not have a value?

Here is my directive:

```
mod.directive('bsInput', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '^form',
    template: '
      <div ng-form="innerForm" class="form-group" ng-class="getFieldClass()"> 
        <label class="control-label" ng-class="{\'col-sm-5\': eVertical }" for="field">{{ eLabel | tt }}</label> 
        <div ng-class="{\'col-sm-7\': eVertical }"> 
          <input type="{{ type }}" class="form-control" name="field" 
            ng-model="ngModel" ng-maxlength="eMaxlength" ng-required="eRequired" 
            ng-disabled="eDisabled" ng-pattern="ePattern" 
            placeholder="{{ePlaceholder}}"> 

            <p class="help-block" ng-show="eHelp">{{eHelp}}</p> 

        </div> 
      </div>',
    scope: {
      ngModel: "=",
      eLabel: "@",
      type: "@",
      eMaxlength: "@",
      eRequired: '=',
      ePattern: '@',
      eVertical: '=',
      eDisabled: '=',
      ePlaceholder: '@',
      eHelp: '@'
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: I think you can try it and provide code on jsfiddle or plnkr, it's better for someone modify it.

Answer (score 0):

You should define in your directive that your properties are optional. e.g.

```
   scope: {
      ngModel: "=",
      eLabel: "@",
      type: "@",
      eMaxlength: "@?", <---------
      eRequired: '=',
      ePattern: '@',
      eVertical: '=',
      eDisabled: '=',
      ePlaceholder: '@',
      eHelp: '@'
    }
```

Then in your link function check if your param is undefined, if it is, set it to empty string. Browser won't do validation against it:

```
link : function(scope, elem, attrs) {
 if (scope.eMaxLength === undefined) {
   scope.eMaxLength = '';
 }
}
```